# how to overwrite date to 1st of month php strtotime and date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Im stuck on what is probably a simple issue but i cant figure it out.

What i am trying to do is take say todays date 2014-08-27
And then change it to the 1st of the month so it would be 2014-08-01

I know i could parse it manually and do it but that seems overkill. Im not that familiar with working with date but none of the 4 examples i tried seem to work. I want to convert it to epoch time once i get the new date

```
$todays_date = date('Y-m-d'); //current date 2014-08-27
```

My 4 fruitless attempts

```
echo "test1: " strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $todays_date)) . "<br />"; // returns -3600
echo "test2: " strtotime('Y-m-d', $todays_date) . "<br />"; // returns nothing
echo "test3: " strtotime('Y-m-01', $todays_date) . "<br />"; // returns nothing
echo "test4: " date('Y-m-01', $todays_date) . "<br />"; // returns nothing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relative time formats make this easy:

```
echo (new DateTime('first day of this month'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

or

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of this month'));
```

Comment: @hek2mgl `the` should be `this`. Classic gotcha.

Comment: The problem is i also use other references to say the 14th of the month. assuming you cant use 'fourteen day of this month' i guess i could just get the 'first day of this month' + 13 days. I assume so its not possible to use Y-m-01, i have seen it suggested in other solutions but maybe the context was different or something.